# Can't click with selenium on service console option of salesforce

Tags: selenium, salesforce, katalon

i'm trying to automate Salesforce Service Console, but i'm having some troubles because the multiples iframes.

One thing i really need is to click on the option "Close all primary tabs", but everything i have tried is not working.

The weird thing is that although the click is done nothing happens, if i try to do a click on chrome inspector console using javascript the tabs are closed, also if i click manually the tabs are closed, but if is made this trought selenium/katalon although the click is done nothing happens.

I have discovered that the popup html source is not under an iframe but the render of the popup overlays a iframe which comes from the external page tab.

If i trick the webpage modifying the css with the inspector moving the popup more up, were there is not iframe, then the click is closing the tabs.

Also if i delete the iframe from the html, the click is closing the tabs.

So i understand that this could be the problem, but although i have tried switch to iframe still not working.

i'am using katalon to automate but also happens with selenium .

Can you help me?

[image: Salesforce Service Console]

*code of the popup list*

```html
<div id="ext-comp-1031"
    class="x-menu x-menu-floating x-layer"
    style="position: absolute; z-index: 15000; visibility: visible; left: 1086px; top: 124px;">
    <a class="x-menu-focus"
        href="#"
        onclick="return false;"
        tabindex="-1"
        id="ext-gen173"/>
    <ul class="x-menu-list"
        id="ext-gen174"
        style="height: 158px;">
        <li id="x-menu-el-ext-comp-1106"
            class="x-menu-list-item">
            <a id="ext-comp-1106"
                class="x-menu-item tab-scroller-menu-item "
                hidefocus="true"
                unselectable="on"
                href="#">
                <img alt=""
                    src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="
                    class="x-menu-item-icon hidden"
                    id="ext-gen526">
                    <span class="x-menu-item-text"
                            id="ext-gen527">
                        <div class="tabTitle">
                            <span class="tabText">External Page</span>
                        </div>
                        <img alt=""
                            src="/s.gif"
                            class="refresh-icon"
                            id="ext-gen538">
                            <div class="x-menu-item-icon burl-link third-position"
                                id="ext-gen539"/>
                            <img alt=""
                                src="/s.gif"
                                class="bookmark-icon bookmarkNoPin"
                                id="ext-gen540"></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="x-menu-el-ext-comp-1107"
                        class="x-menu-list-item">
                        <a id="ext-comp-1107"
                            class="x-menu-item tab-scroller-menu-item x-tab-tabmenu-selected "
                            hidefocus="true"
                            unselectable="on"
                            href="#">
                            <img alt=""
                                src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="
                                class="x-menu-item-icon hidden"
                                id="ext-gen528">
                                <span class="x-menu-item-text"
                                        id="ext-gen529">
                                    <div class="tabTitle">
                                        <span class="tabText">External Page</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <img alt=""
                                        src="/s.gif"
                                        class="refresh-icon"
                                        id="ext-gen541">
                                        <div class="x-menu-item-icon burl-link third-position"
                                            id="ext-gen542"/>
                                        <img alt=""
                                            src="/s.gif"
                                            class="bookmark-icon bookmarkNoPin"
                                            id="ext-gen543"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="x-menu-el-ext-comp-1108"
                                    class="x-menu-list-item">
                                    <a id="ext-comp-1108"
                                        class="x-menu-item x-tab-tabmenu-menuItem"
                                        hidefocus="true"
                                        unselectable="on"
                                        href="#">
                                        <img alt=""
                                            src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="
                                            class="x-menu-item-icon "
                                            id="ext-gen530">
                                            <span class="x-menu-item-text"
                                                    id="ext-gen531">Close all primary tabs</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li id="x-menu-el-ext-comp-1109"
                                        class="x-menu-list-item">
                                        <a id="ext-comp-1109"
                                            class="x-menu-item x-tab-tabmenu-menuItem"
                                            hidefocus="true"
                                            unselectable="on"
                                            href="#">
                                            <img alt=""
                                                src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="
                                                class="x-menu-item-icon "
                                                id="ext-gen532">
                                                <span class="x-menu-item-text"
                                                        id="ext-gen533">Refresh all primary tabs</span>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="x-menu-el-ext-comp-1110"
                                            class="x-menu-list-item">
                                            <a id="ext-comp-1110"
                                                class="x-menu-item x-tab-tabmenu-menuItem"
                                                hidefocus="true"
                                                unselectable="on"
                                                href="#">
                                                <img alt=""
                                                    src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="
                                                    class="x-menu-item-icon "
                                                    id="ext-gen534">
                                                    <span class="x-menu-item-text"
                                                            id="ext-gen535">Reopen last-closed tab</span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li id="x-menu-el-ext-comp-1111"
                                                class="x-menu-list-item">
                                                <a id="ext-comp-1111"
                                                    class="x-menu-item x-tab-tabmenu-menuItem"
                                                    hidefocus="true"
                                                    unselectable="on"
                                                    href="#">
                                                    <img alt=""
                                                        src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="
                                                        class="x-menu-item-icon "
                                                        id="ext-gen536">
                                                        <span class="x-menu-item-text"
                                                                id="ext-gen537">Show keyboard shortcuts (SHIFT+K)</span>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
```

*xpath i'am selecting*

```xml
//*/text()[normalize-space(.)='Close all primary tabs']/parent::*
```

Comment: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML.

Comment: I have updated with the html of the popup and the xpath i'm using to select